# Hiding TCP traffic for Monero miners

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining-pool-setup

Using Wireshark I have noticed that the stratum protocols transmits the JSON strings without encryption.
Is the amount of network traffic high when mining monero? Is it possible that the continuos tcp traffic is raising suspicions for the internet provider?
If my connection is spoofed, how can I mine in total anonymity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the easiest would be to go through VPN, although I don't know exact instructions.

The amount of traffic shouldn't be much considering what's being transmitted and the frequency of it. Possibly increase your mining difficulty so that your miner doesn't spam solved shares every second (which also reduces efficiency of your mining due to communication overhead), but not too much so you don't time-out. Maybe 10s target would be just fine.

There's only one miner which supports SSL connection: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5ow0ch/supportxmr_optimized_claymore_ssl_support/

Comment: So if the difficulty is too low then the miner transmits more traffic, while conversely if it is too high this results in frequent timeouts? How to optimize and minimize the timeout messages? I am currently having a lot of them on my miners.

Comment: By experiment, if your shares take too long, mine at a lower difficulty; if they're too often, increase the difficulty. Trying another pool could help as well, as each will have its own "window" for how long to wait for a share to be solved by some miner.